# how to install my graphic drivers in a VM?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, graphics

I don't want to partially install and try error as I don't want to break my system.

firstly I don't know IF my graphic is installed at all.
secondly I don't know how to install my graphic
thirdly I need to see what openGL my graphic supports.

I'm testing unity 3d beta on linux yes it's a game engine editor going on linux

what happens when I run the project the unity 3d crashes. the installs goes fine and licence

this is what I found to help you guys in helping me:

```
lspci -k | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
    Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: vmwgfx
    Kernel modules: vmwgfx
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: e1000

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

and yes it is a virtual environment
I gave it:

```
50GB storage
2048 RAM
80MB VRAM
```

and why I shouldn't be testing beta on virtual environment?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? It is a virtual machine, so no drivers can be installed.

Comment: And virtual machines are not the environment where you should be trying Unity 3D engine.

Comment: oh it is a virtual machine, why shouldn't I try unity 3d on virtual?

Comment: @MilitaryG Because a virtual machine is not powerful enough, and its graphics capabilities are limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VM is virtual, so its graphics processor is virtual too. For this reason you can't install the proprietary graphics driver for the graphics card in your physical machine in a virtual machine. Instead you should use the graphics driver that is included in VMware. Allocating more video memory in the VMware settings may alleviate the low-graphics mode problem. In VMware Workstation 11 up to 2GB of video memory can be allocated for additional workload processing power. VMware Workstation 15 and later supports virtual graphics memory up to 3GB. The Ubuntu guest OS doesn't need to be booted and running in order to change its settings in VMware.